# Understanding formalization of equivalence relation on fibres of a function

Tags: proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to understand a point in my professor's lecture notes on equivalence relations.

First, we define a function $f: S \to T$ with $a \sim b$ if and only if $f(a) = f(b)$. This is surely an equivalence relation, and the partition of $S$ is given by $S = \bigsqcup\limits_{t \in \mathrm{Im}(f) \subset T} f^{-1} (t)$. We can then say that $f$ factors through the quotient via the composition of maps
\begin{align*}
\underset{a}{S} \underset{\longmapsto}{\twoheadrightarrow} \underset{[a]}{S/\sim} \; \; \underset{\longmapsto}{\hookrightarrow} \underset{f(a)}{T}.
\end{align*}
so if $\pi$ is the canonical projection map and $\varphi$ the map $[a] \to f(a)$, then $f = \varphi \circ \pi$.

The next point he makes doesn't make any sense to me. He writes:
\begin{align*}
\text{equivalence relation on $S$} \iff & \text{ partition of $S$ into disjoint subsets } \\
\iff & \text{ surjective map from $S$ to another set $T$} \\
& \text{(up to composition with a bijection $T \stackrel{\sim}{\to} T'$)}.
\end{align*}
The first biconditional makes sense. If we have an equivalence relation on $S$, we get a partition of $S$ into equivalence classes. Conversely, given a partition of $S $, we can define an equivalence relation by the rule that $a$ is related to $b$ if they live in the same set in  the partition.

I do not understand the argument behind second biconditional or its implication. In the above example, for instance, there is no surjective map from $S \to T$, but from $S \to S/\sim$, the set of equivalence classes, which is then embedded in $T$. I'm also not sure what he means to "up to composition with a bijection $T \to T'$, since $T$ is by definition the codomain of $f$.

UPDATE: After thinking about this more and reading the very helpful answers below, I think what he is saying is that if there is some other function $G: S \to T$ that induces the same equivalence relation, we can "compose" with the bijection $T \to T'$ sending $f(a)$ to $g(a)$. The equivalence classes are determined by the fibers, so we don't require $f(a) = g(a)$ for every $a$. Is this the correct idea?

Comment: The composite map from $S$ to $S / \sim$ to $T$ is indeed surjective.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now. But what does "up to composition with a bijection $T \to T'$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

The composite map from $S$ to $S / \sim$ to $T$ (which in fact equals $f$) is surjective.

Your professor means the following:

Given a particular equivalence relation $\sim \subseteq S^2$, there are potentially many choices $f : S \to T$ of surjective functions such that $\{(a, b) | f(a) = f(b)\} = \sim$.

For example, consider the set $A = \{1, 2\}$ and the equivalence relation $\{(1, 1), (2, 2)\}$. This equivalence relation is induced by

$x \mapsto x : A \to A$

$x \mapsto x + 1 : A \to \{2, 3\}$

$x \mapsto 2 - x : A \to A$

etc.

You'll notice that all of these functions have something in common: their codomain is in bijection with $A$.

We consider two functions $f : A \to B$ and $g : A \to C$ to be equivalent if there is a bijection $h : B \to C$ such that $h \circ f = g$. Note that this is in fact an equivalence relation. Furthermore, note that if $f$ is surjective and $g$ is equivalent to $f$, $g$ is also surjective. Finally, note that surjective functions can be equivalent "in at most one way" (meaning that there is at most one bijection $h : B \to C$ such that $h \circ f = g$).

Your professor is stating that if two surjective maps $f : A \to B$ and $g : A \to C$ give the same induced equivalence relation $\sim$, then the two maps are equivalent under the above definition. Conversely, if the two maps are equivalent under the above equivalence relation, they will produce the same equivalence relation on $A$.

The "canonical" way of taking an equivalence relation $\sim$ and getting a surjective function $f$ is by taking the projection map $f : A \to A / \sim$, which is defined using equivalence classes.

Comment: This is extremely helpful and I really appreciate it. Though I believe I understand everything you wrote, I'm still having trouble with the precise terminology he used. "Up to," in my understanding, means signals a notion of "equivalence," and it makes sense to me that there could be more than. one equivalence relation inducing the same partition. But why then would the bijection be $T \to T'$? Is the idea to add another bijection to the string and write a surjection $S \to T'$, which is fine provided that the equivalence relations induced are the same?

Comment: After thinking about this more, I think what you're saying is that the particular set $T$ doesn't really matter, because if I have another function $g: S \to T'$ that induces the equivalence relation in question, I can still write exactly the same chain of functions. Technically, I suppose that would be "composing with $g$ at the end and going from $f(a) \to g(a)$. Is that right?